# What's the difference between "exposed to" and "subjected to"?

Tags: difference

What's the difference between the two expressions "exposed to" and "subjected to" in the context of a risk?

Example:

> Because of this they will continue to be defenselessly exposed/subjected to the effects/repercussions of the current monetary system.

Comment: have you seen either phrase used in any examples.  Please include those examples in your question.

Comment: @JamesK I've added an example in the question.

Comment: Thanks, where is the quote from?

Comment: I'm writing an article and English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Subject to" means that it is likely to be affected, or is already affected by something.

> The finance department is subject to random inspections by the auditors.

This means that the auditors often inspect the department.

On the other hand "exposed" to means it would be affected if the event occurs.

> The company is exposed to losses if the stock market crashes.

This means that if the stock market crashed, the company might lose money.

So in your situation are they at risk and therefore exposed. Or are they already affected, and so subject?

Comment: Thank you @JamesK! This helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

"Subject" imples (1) the use of force and/or (2) intentionality, which I think are not inherently implied with "expose".  That is why it is more likely for someone to "subject" someone else, but to "expose" themselves.

- He was sent there, subjecting him to the risk.
- He went there, exposing himself to the risk.

Comment: Thanks heaps @Bernie6. Your answer is helpful too!